# Is there a way to create a folder dynamically based on the first part of the filename in talend before copying the sftp file

Tags: java, directory, filenames, talend

I am downloading a file from the remote sftp site and based on the filename for eg:A_B_C.csv before using tfilecopy in talend to transfer the file onto a local folder,how can i create a new folder based on the first part of the filename just before delimiter_(folder called A in this case) and then copy the file onto the specific folder called A?

Or even a java code to parse the filename and extract only A field from the filename (A_B_C.csv) and create a folder/directory and then copy the retrieved file into the same folder

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a tJava, placing it between tFileList and tFileCopy.
Extract the part preceding "*" with an expression like `((String)globalMap.get("tFileList_1_CURRENT_FILE")).split("_")[0]`
(perhaps you will have to test if file contains "*" before splitting, otherwise you'll be exposed to null pointer exceptions).

Place it in a context or global variable.

Then use this variable in tFileCopy.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the input,i will try that,so after using tjava to check for null pointers and splitting the first part of the filename,how do i make a folder using A(from the filename) and copy the file into that folder?

Comment: in your tFileCopy component, simply put your variable as the target repository , like "C:/temp/"+context.myVariable.